# TableView Slow Scroll

Tags: ios, performance, scroll, tableview

I'm developing and iOS app and my UITableView is kinda slow. I would like to know all the possible reasons for a slow scroll.
Note that I'm using prototype cells in the storyboard and I don't have any images.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    Classification *classification = [classifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *teamLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    [teamLabel setText:[classification team]];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return cell;

}
```

Also, it runs smoothly in the simulator.
I'm using an iPad 2.

Comment: If you could post your implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method… that would be great

Comment: is data coming from web service ?

Comment: edited. yes it is coming from a webservice. I parse the data into custom objects and then save them into an array. the tableview is reading from that array.

Comment: you seem too often updates the table. try call reloadData after for example 10 times of receive data from server or check do you download data in main thread.

Comment: I'm downloading the data only once, on viewDidLoad, and I'm using AFNetworking

Comment: I've run the allocation tool in the instruments and it pointed out the following line as problematic: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

Answer (score 0):

Download the data asynchronously in your:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Use 2 separated UITableViewCell objects, one to fill with text data, one for images which need to be in thread such as `dispatch_async`, example from my project:

```
if (imageUrl.length > 0)
        {
            NSString *completeURL = @"";
            completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:kPROFILE_IMAGE_URL];
            completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:@"/2/"];
            completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:imageUrl];
            completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageUrl];
            NSString* path = GetMediaFolder();
            BOOL imageExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

            if (imageExists)
            {
                // NSLog(@"Image exists");
                // Update UI

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    UITableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[updateCell viewWithTag:kTAG_IMAGE];
                    imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
                    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 23.0;
                    imageView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);
                    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
                    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

                    [updateCell setNeedsLayout];
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // NSLog(@"Image not exists");
                // Download The Image

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
                {
                    NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:completeURL];
                    NSData *image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                    [image writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] atomically:YES];

                    // Update UI
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                    {
                        UITableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[updateCell viewWithTag:kTAG_IMAGE];
                        imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
                        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 23.0;
                        imageView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);
                        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
                        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

                        [updateCell setNeedsLayout];
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
```

**EDIT 1:**

I see you don't use images, you still need to download all the data asynchronously and fill it in the new `UITableViewCell` when download finished (instead of my images downloads, temporary data and downloaded data).

Comment: I don't think that apply to my case... I only download data once form the webservice and then the custom objects stay in memory.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if you use the downloaded data in your UITableView then this is what you need. Don't first download the data, wait for it and then fill it.